# iOS App quitting without any crash log

Tags: ios, crash

My App is quitting without any crash log(just showing "gdb"). On taking detail log by symbolicating, i am getting the following. Have you have any idea why this happening? Please help.....

```
Thread 5 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35d2132c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x34f09208 pthread_kill + 48
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x34f02298 abort + 88
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x35519f64 abort_message + 40
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x35517346 _ZL17default_terminatev + 18
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x338cf350 _objc_terminate + 140
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x355173be _ZL19safe_handler_callerPFvvE + 70
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3551744a std::terminate() + 14
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x35518798 __cxa_throw + 116
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x338cf290 objc_exception_throw + 88
10  CoreFoundation                  0x35caea94 -[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:] +     168
11  CoreFoundation                  0x35cad90e ___forwarding___ + 294
12  CoreFoundation                  0x35c08648 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 40
13  UIKit                           0x333cad06 -[UIView(Rendering) contentMode] + 294
14  UIKit                           0x333c9dfe -[UIImageView(UIImageViewInternal) _canDrawContent] + 230
15  UIKit                           0x333ca88a -[UIImageView(UIImageViewInternal) _updateState] + 22
16  UIKit                           0x333ca1a0 -[UIImageView setImage:] + 300
17  MyApp                       0x000353e0 0x30000 + 21472
18  MyApp                       0x00034098 0x30000 + 16536
19  MyApp                       0x00034ee6 0x30000 + 20198
20  Foundation                      0x35046a7a -[NSThread main] + 66
21  Foundation                      0x350da58a __NSThread__main__ + 1042
22  libsystem_c.dylib               0x34eca72e _pthread_start + 314
23  libsystem_c.dylib               0x34eca5e8 thread_start + 0
```

Comment: Have you tried Zoombie?

Comment: yes. But no benefit. Didn't gt any extra logs

Comment: Without any code we cant help you?

Comment: Start debugging, put log and/or break points, to point out the closest code causing crash then add that code snippet with your question.

Comment: ok I'll try by doing that

Answer (score 2):

try this way:

[image]

[image]

its show you all exception when app crash....

Answer (score 0):

You can get the crash reason when running the application on a device. Usually when running the app on a device generates a log in both xcode and Organizer Device Log. YOu can check from there easily why its crashing.

Comment: I tried that. But it's showing "unknown" in device logs of organizer.
I exported and symbolicated it, but no luck

Comment: have you seen it in the Organizer log ?

Comment: Yes, in organizer it's showing unknown

Comment: can u post what it is showing in organizer when app crashes?